# Yii2 validate by second model with when validator

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Is it possible to make validation by another model by when validator? What I mean is:

```
return [
            [['user_id', 'country_id', 'region_id', 'city_id'], 'integer'],
            [['name', 'address', 'eik', 'mol', 'dds'], 'string'],
            [['name', 'address', 'mol'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['eik'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['dds'], 'string', 'max' => 1],
            [
                [
                    'user_id',
                    'country_id',
                    'region_id',
                    'city_id',
                    'name',
                    'address',
                    'eik',
                    'mol',
                    'dds',
                ],
                'required',
                'on' => self::SCENARIO_UPDATE,
                'when' => function($model ( THIS SHOULD BE THE SECOND MODEL ) ){
                    return $model->someField;
                },
                'whenClient' => 'function(attribute, value){
                    return $("#someSelector").val() == 2
                }'
            ]
        ];
```

Where the `$model` in `when` condition is let's say `model B`. When I add value to `model B` field the validation should be enabled. In client part I can choose any field by it's selector but is it possible with the server-side part?

Comment: I don't think so... What about custom methods? Is that fine?

Comment: Yes, will try this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign this related model to main model:

```
$model = new MyModel();
$model->someModel = new SomeModel();

$model->someModel->load(Yii::app()->request->post());
$model->load(Yii::app()->request->post());
```

And then in validation rules of `MyModel`:

```
'when' => function($model){
    return $model->someModel->someField;
},
```

---

But if you have such problem, then this is a good sign that you should not use `ActiveRecord` directly to handle this form. You should rather create separated form model dedicated to handle this specified form and all its fields.

Comment: Than you! Will try tomorrow and will give a feedback.

Answer (score -1):

not the best solution i guess but you can try this:

```
'when' => function(){
    if(Yii::$app->request->post('YOUR_MODEL_B')['YOUR_ATTRIBUTE']=="whatever"){
        // do your thing    
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a very good indeed. What if `POST` does not contain such array index? Then you would get a `notice` error.

Comment: Using `POST` in model is generally a bad advice. Active record should be context-independent - it should work even in console environment, where there is no POST data.